# Reopen request following addition of research results

Tags: discussion

The question [The origin of "knickers in a knot" and "knickers in a twist"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341833/the-origin-of-knickers-in-a-knot-and-knickers-in-a-twist) was closed for lack of research. I have added a paragraph to the question pointing out that in a reputable and fairly recent dictionary of idioms (the 1998 *Cambridge International Dictionary of Idioms*) the entry for the phrases that the poster asks about does not answer the poster's question about their exact origin.

Since the question now shows some research, I think it ought not remain closed for not showing research. Please consider voting to reopen it. Thanks.

Comment: I already voted to reopen.

Comment: Me too, saw it in the review queue, VtRO.

Comment: The question has been reopened. Thanks to all who took time to weigh reopening it in light of the additional content in the question.

Comment: I believe that a custom flag for a moderator explaining that *you are interested in answering* the question would be the go next time. Based on your reputation I am sure your request will be entertained. I also believe that posting a meta-thread which then days after will be featured/hot is really *not* the way to go.

Comment: @Matsmath: I posted my answer at a time when the question was open but had two or three close votes. When the the close vote total got to four, I edited the question to show research, as lack of research by the OP was the close reason that the four close voters cited. A fifth close voter then voted to close anyway—and then I petitioned via this Meta question to have it reopened on grounds that the close reason should be deemed satisfied. Such petitions are common and (I think) reasonable at EL&U Meta. I have no idea why the question briefly became featured/hot on SE, but I'm sorry it did.

Comment: ...I might add that my reopen request does have a discussion component: Is it appropriate for a person who has answered a question that subsequently gets closed for lack of research by the original poster to supply the perceived deficiency in original research by adding research to the question? By posting my reopen request to EL&U Meta, I was asking for support for reopening from EL&U participants, but I was also giving people who disapprove of the behavior I just described a chance to voice their opposition in whatever detail they considered appropriate. Your dissent is the only one so far.